# Ovirt Python SDK and Sysprep

Tags: python, kvm, sysprep

I understand how to set an OS hostname in CloudInit for a Linux VM using the Python SDK like below, but how would I do the same thing for setting an OS hostname in a Windows VM using Sysprep?  I can’t find any examples of this anywhere.

```
                   action = params.Action(
                     vm=params.VM(
                       initialization=params.Initialization(
                           cloud_init=params.CloudInit(
                               host=params.Host(address="rheltest001.example.com")
                           )
                        )   
                      )
                   )
                   vm.start( action )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass *host_name* argument to Initialization constructor:

```
              action = params.Action(
                 vm=params.VM(
                   initialization=params.Initialization(
                       cloud_init=params.CloudInit(
                           host=params.Host(address="rheltest001.example.com")
                       ),
                       host_name='rheltest001.example.com'
                    )   
                  )
               )
               vm.start( action )
```